# How can I change the Date column format in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert the date to Day, Month and Year. I tried some alternatives, but I was unsuccessful.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Instagram\Postagem.xlsx")

print(df)
```

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74905151/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very confusing, because you're using two different formats between the image and the expected result (and you write you want the same).

Clarify that data is a date with:

```
df['data']= = pd.to_datetime(df['data'])
```

Once you have this, just change the format with:

```
my_format = '%m-%d-%Y'
df['data'] = df['data'].dt.strftime(my_format)
```

Comment: thank you was what i needed.

the excel file is correct, I don't know why Pandas is printing the wrong date.